# styles appear to be applied incorrectly in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, less

I am using LessCSS to create a simple metro theme website.  I have the following in my variables.less file:

```
@unit: 30px;
@tileMargin: 2px;
```

this in my mixins.less:

```
.tile(@xDim, @yDim, @color){
    display: inline-block;
    margin: @tileMargin;
    width: @xDim * @unit + 2 * (@xDim - 1) * @tileMargin;
    height: @yDim * @unit + 2 * (@yDim - 1) * @tileMargin;
    .gradient-bottom-right(@color);
}

.tile-container(@width, @height){
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: @height * @unit + 2 * (@height - 1) * @tileMargin + 2 * @tileMargin;
    width: @width * @unit + 2 * (@width - 1) * @tileMargin + 2 * @tileMargin;
}
```

To guarantee that multiples of a unit square maintain the proper size despite element margins.  However, when I actually test this with two 5x5 tile and a 10x5 tile I get a weird spacing between my tiles.

Examples of the errors (I added the border on the container for clarity):

[image: The distance between those boxes is substantially greater than 2 pixels]

If I remove the inline-block statement, the tiles will have the correct spacing between each other, but no longer the correct relationship with the parent div (breaking out of the parent) and naturally no longer wanting to stay next to each other.  How do I remove this annoying spacing?  I want to avoid floats at all costs.

EDIT: Just confirmed this same problem occurs in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

`inline-block` will respect any text nodes you have in the DOM (you have spaces between the divs). Try placing the elements right next to each other with no spaces.